# ElasticSearch Term Query for multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

My below elasticsearch query responding me with 0 records. While, if I queried upon **Approved** or **Declined** separately, it is giving me the exact result which I want.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "responseType": "Approved"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "responseType": "Declined"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

Comment: Since I don't think that `responseType` can have multiple values, you want `Approved OR Declined` not `Approved AND Declined`, correct?

Comment: I will Have Approved, Declined, Error, None.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Do you want `AND` or `OR` semantics?

Comment: I want multiple value, like I need the values with `Approved` as well as `Declined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `OR` semantics, then you have two options:

Option 1: `bool/should` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "responseType.keyword": "Approved"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "responseType.keyword": "Declined"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "must": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

Option 2: `terms` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "responseType.keyword": ["Approved", "Declined"]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

Comment: Getting below result for both you given

```
{
 "took": 0,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
  "total": 1,
  "successful": 1,
  "skipped": 0,
  "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
  "total": {
   "value": 0,
   "relation": "eq"
  },
  "max_score": null,
  "hits": []
 }
}
```

Comment: Strange, if your initial query worked, these two should also work. Can you share your index mapping please?

Comment: ```
"mappings": {
   "properties": {
    "responseType": {
     "type": "text",
     "fields": {
      "keyword": {
       "type": "keyword",
       "ignore_above": 256
      }
     }
    },
    "transactionType": {
     "type": "text",
     "fields": {
      "keyword": {
       "type": "keyword",
       "ignore_above": 256
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the queries to use the right field, i.e. the `.keyword` sub-field. Please try again.